# Wrapping text around an image when the image is listed after the text in html

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I'm working in a system where I can modify the CSS but not the HTML (can't use javascript either). I'm trying to get the text to wrap around an image placed in the top right of a page. The problem I've been having is that every solution I've found requires that the image be listed before the text in the html. Is there a way around this? Thanks!

```css
<style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
        img {
            display:block;
            float:none;
            margin:0 auto 20px !important;
        }
    }
</style>
```

```html
<div style="Margin:20px;">

            <p style="Margin:0; font:16px/1.25 sans-serif; color:#4CB3E8; text-align:justify;">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, aut eligendi dignissimos, illum eaque ut architecto quisquam! Odio, aliquam eligendi iste tempore beatae, deserunt! Officia temporibus at, debitis excepturi porro mollitia aspernatur labore unde dolores quae blanditiis dignissimos error aut iure magnam sed placeat impedit incidunt praesentium natus dolorum.                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, aut eligendi dignissimos, illum eaque ut architecto quisquam! Odio, aliquam eligendi iste tempore beatae, deserunt! Officia temporibus at, debitis excepturi porro mollitia aspernatur labore unde dolores quae blanditiis dignissimos error aut iure magnam sed placeat impedit incidunt praesentium natus dolorum.                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, aut eligendi dignissimos, illum eaque ut architecto quisquam! Odio, aliquam eligendi iste tempore beatae, deserunt! Officia temporibus at, debitis excepturi porro mollitia aspernatur labore unde dolores quae blanditiis dignissimos error aut iure magnam sed placeat impedit incidunt praesentium natus dolorum.                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, aut eligendi dignissimos, illum eaque ut architecto quisquam! Odio, aliquam eligendi iste tempore beatae, deserunt! Officia temporibus at, debitis excepturi porro mollitia aspernatur labore unde dolores quae blanditiis dignissimos error aut iure magnam sed placeat impedit incidunt praesentium natus dolorum.                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, aut eligendi dignissimos, illum eaque ut architecto quisquam! Odio, aliquam eligendi iste tempore beatae, deserunt! Officia temporibus at, debitis excepturi porro mollitia aspernatur labore unde dolores quae blanditiis dignissimos error aut iure magnam sed placeat impedit incidunt praesentium natus dolorum.                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, aut eligendi dignissimos, illum eaque ut architecto quisquam! Odio, aliquam eligendi iste tempore beatae, deserunt! Officia temporibus at, debitis excepturi porro mollitia aspernatur labore unde dolores quae blanditiis dignissimos error aut iure magnam sed placeat impedit incidunt praesentium natus dolorum.                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, aut eligendi dignissimos, illum eaque ut architecto quisquam! Odio, aliquam eligendi iste tempore beatae, deserunt! Officia temporibus at, debitis excepturi porro mollitia aspernatur labore unde dolores quae blanditiis dignissimos error aut iure magnam sed placeat impedit incidunt praesentium natus dolorum.                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, aut eligendi dignissimos, illum eaque ut architecto quisquam! Odio, aliquam eligendi iste tempore beatae, deserunt! Officia temporibus at, debitis excepturi porro mollitia aspernatur labore unde dolores quae blanditiis dignissimos error aut iure magnam sed placeat impedit incidunt praesentium natus dolorum.                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, aut eligendi dignissimos, illum eaque ut architecto quisquam! Odio, aliquam eligendi iste tempore beatae, deserunt! Officia temporibus at, debitis excepturi porro mollitia aspernatur labore unde dolores quae blanditiis dignissimos error aut iure magnam sed placeat impedit incidunt praesentium natus dolorum.                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, aut eligendi dignissimos, illum eaque ut architecto quisquam! Odio, aliquam eligendi iste tempore beatae, deserunt! Officia temporibus at, debitis excepturi porro mollitia aspernatur labore unde dolores quae blanditiis dignissimos error aut iure magnam sed placeat impedit incidunt praesentium natus dolorum.                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, aut eligendi dignissimos, illum eaque ut architecto quisquam! Odio, aliquam eligendi iste tempore beatae, deserunt! Officia temporibus at, debitis excepturi porro mollitia aspernatur labore unde dolores quae blanditiis dignissimos error aut iure magnam sed placeat impedit incidunt praesentium natus dolorum.                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, aut eligendi dignissimos, illum eaque ut architecto quisquam! Odio, aliquam eligendi iste tempore beatae, deserunt! Officia temporibus at, debitis excepturi porro mollitia aspernatur labore unde dolores quae blanditiis dignissimos error aut iure magnam sed placeat impedit incidunt praesentium natus dolorum.                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, aut eligendi dignissimos, illum eaque ut architecto quisquam! Odio, aliquam eligendi iste tempore beatae, deserunt! Officia temporibus at, debitis excepturi porro mollitia aspernatur labore unde dolores quae blanditiis dignissimos error aut iure magnam sed placeat impedit incidunt praesentium natus dolorum.
            </p>
              <img src="http://i.imgur.com/6bkt2Qk.gif" align="right" width="140" height="140" border="0" style="Margin:0 0 20px 20px; background:#E79851;" />
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean: "that the image is listed before the text in HTML." you want text around the picture?

Comment: I mean that in the html, it's
<p>
<img>

instead of 
<img>
<p>

Comment: what should this bring you? what do you want to achieve with this?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a way to do what you're describing, but you could definitely create a workaround, something like this:

```css
img{
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

div#main::before{
  content: "";
  float: right;
  margin: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas. Vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque. Sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper. Gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim. Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. In iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Quis commodo odio aenean sed. Sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi. Metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed. Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Facilisis volutpat est velit egestas.

Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Id eu nisl nunc mi. Varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget. Amet dictum sit amet justo donec enim. Diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec. Integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet. Magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris. Duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat. Ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod. Sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis. Lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra. Viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt.

Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris. Elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris. Dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra. Lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum. Nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur. Congue eu consequat ac felis donec. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis. Mi proin sed libero enim. Risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et. Amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra. Tristique magna sit amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus.

Vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer. Aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna. Eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum. Vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Dignissim diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et. Nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras. Tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus. Ornare arcu odio ut sem. Nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut. Diam in arcu cursus euismod. Morbi tristique senectus et netus. Senectus et netus et malesuada  fames ac turpis egestas. Duis at consectetur lorem donec massa. Tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id. Sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia.
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. My only issue with this is that I don't necessarily know what the height of my image will be, so I can't set the margin accurately.